# Run Servlet in ubuntu 10.10 using tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I have install tomcat and jdk6 in ubuntu 10.10. I tried to create servlets in var/www folder but when i run them using browser with address localhost:8080/ but it reply that you do not have permission to access index.html on this server. So can any one help me out....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with a good tutorial:

http://www.cs.wcupa.edu/~rkline/Ubuntu/tomcat.html

You absolutely need to do just a bit more than put a .jsp file in your Apache root folder.

Eclipse can help you out big time - I'd encourage you to try it (per the above tutorial).

Good luck!